# limit of a sequence related to functions

Tags: real-analysis

There is a course of analysis, there are solutions ptovided for problems but firstly one has to enter the correct answer. I'm curious about the solution for this but not smart enough to solve

let f is a function differentiable in a. $x_n = n(f(a + \frac{1}{n}) - f(a))$
Find $lim\ x_n$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Also, please use more descriptive titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By differentiability of $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ at $a$, observe that the map $g : \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$g(x) = \frac{f(a+x) - f(a)}{x}$$
satisfies $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = f'(a)$. Since $n^{-1}\to 0$, it follows that $x_n = g(n^{-1}) \to f'(a)$.

Comment: thanks. and why that all is multiplied by n? it's a number of $x_n$ afaik I still can't understand why it's n(f(a+1/n)−f(a)), not f(a+1/n)−f(a)